# JsonRequestBehavior issue when migrating to ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-core, json.net

I am migrating an application from .NET 4.5 to Core 3.1 and I have an odd problem. This is what my controller used to look like

```
    public ActionResult GetNById(int id)
    {
        var model = cerRepo.GetNById(id);
        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult GetAllKO()
    {
        var result = cerRepo.GetAllKO();
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    #endregion


    public ActionResult GetAllUL()
    {
        var result = cerRepo.GetAllUL();
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    #endregion


    public ActionResult GetHN (string str)
    {
        var result = cerRepo.GetHNS (str);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult GetGrP (string id )
    {
        var result = cerRepo.GetGrP(id);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
```

I was using `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` but I am not using it in Core since it's no longer used right? So now my controller looks like this

```
public ActionResult GetNById(int id)
    {
        var model = cerRepo.GetNById(id);

        return Json(model);
    }


    public ActionResult GetAllKO()
    {
        var result = cerRepo.GetAllKO();
        return Json(result);
    }

    #region action :: get all street
    public ActionResult GetAllUL()
    {
        var result = cerRepo.GetAllUL();
        return Json(result);
    }

    public ActionResult GetHN(string str)
    {
        var result = cerRepo.GetHNS(str);
        return Json(result);
    }

    public ActionResult GetGrP(string id)
    {
        var result = cerRepo.GetGrP(id);
        return Json(result);
    }
```

I am now getting an error saying 
**Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED /Controller/GetALLUL**
as well as 
**Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED /Controller/GetALLKO**

I used JsonRequestBehavior everywhere in the first place, but now I only get the error with **GetALLUL** & **GetALLKO**

What could be causing the issue?

Comment: What is the issue you are seeing?

Comment: Sorry, something must have happened with my original post and some stuff are missing. I get an error in console `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED :44393/Controller/GetAllUL:1`
as well as 
`net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED :44393/Controller/GetAlLKO:1`

Comment: Do those two actions return huge data or like takes more time  to execute than the alloted time for request (ideally, IIS allocates 90 seconds for a request). Just making a guess here as others but these two are working .